# Joint Prior Distribution for Uniform$(a,b)$ ($a,b$ unknown)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, bayesian

I have some problems in figuring out how to address the following problem and some help would be welcomed.

> **Exercise**
>
> Consider a Continuous Uniform Distribution over the $
> (a,b)$ interval where $a< b$ are both unknown parameters.
>
> a) Find a joint prior distribution for the vector of parameters $(a,b)$ such that it is conjugate family for the Uniform$(a,b)$ distribution.
>
> b) Based on a) find the prior marginal distribution for each parameter.

Comment: Copula's model?

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/433414/joint-prior-distribution-for-uniforma-b-a-b-unknown.